# Split cell string into individual cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am unable to split a single cell's value into two different strings and put both of those strings in different cells.

For instance I want to take a measurement `10ft x 20ft` value in a cell and take the `10ft` and put it in another cell, and take the `20ft` and put it in a completely different cell.

I'd like to use a delimiter `x` or something, but I just don't know how to take those separations and do something with them after the split.

Any tips would be much appreciated.  I'm still pretty new to VBA macros.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is using SPLIT

```
Dim strX As String
Dim sx() As String
Dim i as Integer
strX = "10FT x 20FT"
sx = Split(strX, "x")
```

Or maybe you can use instr function

```
Dim sVar1 as string
Dim sVar2 as string

I = InStr(1, strX, "x")
```

Now you know where can split int two variables

```
sVar1 = mid(strX, 1, I)
sVar2 = mid(strx,i+1)
```

The problem with the function is that if you have several keys in the chain with which you want to separate your function will return an array larger.
For example:
Dim var as string
var = "x 20XP 10XP"

returns

```
array (0) = "10"
array (1) = "p"
array (2) = "20"
array (3) = "p"
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that variation as well.

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need VBA. You can use Excel's Text to Columns

For example, in [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010)

1. Data ..... *Text to Columns*
2. Pick `delimited` and press *Next*
3. Check *Space* and put 'x' in *Other* and press *Next*
4. Finish

[image]

Comment: Wow, that is handy.  I had no idea that was there.  Shows how much I know.  However since I'm automating this after I get the manual portion working, I will be using VBA to just do it for me.

Comment: @cheapkid1 If **Text to Columns** works then you can use that from VBA as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns

Answer (score 1):

Guess I just needed to look a little harder.

```
Sub Split_CutArea()
Dim str1() As String
Dim str2() As String
Dim avarsplit As Variant

avarsplit = Split(Cells(4, "B").Value, "x")
splitValues = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, "B").Value)

ActiveSheet.Cells(22, "B").Value = splitValues(0) & splitValues(1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(23, "B").Value = splitValues(3) & splitValues(4)   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that other 'End Sub' was a part of a Public Class, so I was just showing the part that applied, next time I'll be more carefull to delete what doesn't belong.