# Excel 2010 VBA. Concatenate 2 columns from a Sheet and paste them in another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, concatenation

Using Excel 2010, I'm trying to create a script that concatenates two text columns (A and B) from Sheet1 and pastes the result in column A of Sheet2.

The workbook uses an external datasource for loading both columns, so the number of rows is not fixed.

I've tried the following code, but not working. variable lRow is not taking any value.

```
Sub Concat()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lRow
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2)
Next i

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to what are you doing wrong, I suggest you use

```
Sub Concat()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Debug.Print rng.Address(External:=True)
    lRow = rng.Row
    For i = 2 To lRow
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

to see what is going on. I tried exactly what you used and it worked for me (Excel 2010).

Specifying what does "variable lRow is not taking any value" mean would help.

You could also try alternatively

```
Sub Concat2()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2").End(xlDown)
    Debug.Print rng.Address(External:=True)
    lRow = rng.Row
    For i = 2 To lRow
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

which should give the same result if yo do not have blank cells in the middle of the source column A.

Comment: @JackCasas - Is "variable lRow is not taking any value" an error message that Excel gives you? Did you try debugging any of the `Sub`s (yours, or any of the two I posted)? Set a breakpoint at `For ...` and check the value of lRow. Also check the output in the immediate window, and post it back here. Good luck.

Comment: Got it done! I was not creating the macro correctly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would advise getting out of the `.Select` method of XL VBA programming in favor of direct addressing that will not leave you hanging with errors.

```
Sub Concat()
    Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lRow
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 2)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the periods (aka . or *full stop*) that prefix `.Cells` and `.Range`. These tell .Cells and .Range that they belong to the worksheet referenced in the `With ... End With` block; in this example that would be `Sheets("Sheet1")`.

If you have a lot of rows to string together you would be better off creating an array of the values from Sheet1 and processing the concatenation in memory. Split off the concatenated values and return them to Sheet2.

```
Sub concat2()
    Dim c As Long, rws As Long, vCOLab As Variant
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        rws = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
        vCOLab = .Range("A2").Resize(rws, 3)
        For c = LBound(vCOLab, 1) To UBound(vCOLab, 1)
            'Debug.Print vCOLab(c, 1) & vCOLab(c, 2)
            vCOLab(c, 3) = vCOLab(c, 1) & vCOLab(c, 2)
        Next c
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(rws, 1) = Application.Index(vCOLab, , 3)
End Sub
```

When interacting with a worksheet, bulk operations will beat a loop every time; the only question is by how much.