# Breaking a string into different columns based on a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to break my string in MS Excel into different columns based on unique identifier, i.e. "."

I need to break the below string,

```
1.1.4.1.10.3
```

Formulae should give me below shown results in 6 different columns,

```
1  1  4  1  10  3
```

Would really appreciate any kind of help!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Creating an excel worksheet Macro](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9274700/4519059).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Text To Columns command that comes with Excel:

Select the cells with the data. It should be only one column.
Click Data > Text to Columns
Select "delimited" and click <kbd>Next</kbd>
Tick the box next to "Other" and enter a dot, then click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Comment: Thanks teylyn, but I need to do it through formulas as it a recurring task (not through text to column) ..... if you can help me with formulas, it'd be great.

Comment: You should edit your question and clearly state the requirement for a **formula solution**. Otherwise, the question will be closed, since similar questions have been asked and answered before. You need to explain WHY the text-to-column approach is not an option. This approach can be automated with VBA and it will work for strings with many, many delimiter dots. If you need a formula, it will be a very complicated construct of nested If statements. Not ideal. Please revise your question.